# Hilbert 90 for cyclic Galois ring extension

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, group-cohomology

All the rings will be commutative with 1.

**Definition.** Let $S/R$ be a ring extension (that is, $R$ is a subring of $S$), and let $G$ be a (finite) subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}_{R-\text{alg}}(S)$. We say that $S/R$ is a Galois extension of group $G$ if $R=S^G$ and one of the following equivalent condition holds:

(i) The map $x\otimes y\in S\otimes_R S\mapsto (x\sigma(y))_{\sigma\in G}\in S^{\vert G\vert}$ is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras

(ii) There exists $x_1,y_1,...,x_n,y_n\in S$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sigma(y_i)=\delta_{\sigma,Id_S}$ for all $\sigma\in G$

(iii) For each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{M}$ of $S$ and each $\sigma\in G\setminus\{Id_S\}, $there exists $x\in S$ such that $\sigma(x)-x\notin \mathfrak{M}$.

There are also equivalent definitions involving trivial crossed product algebras, but i do not want to come into that.

**Context.** The following result is well-known: if ${\rm Pic}(R)=0$, then $H^1(G,S^\times)=1$ (see for example, Ford, separable algebras, Corollary 13.3.2)

In particular, for cyclic groups,  the well-known description of the cohomology of cyclic groups yields :

**Prop.** Assume that $S/R$ is Galois, with cyclic Galois group. Let $\sigma$ be a generator of the Galois group. Assume that ${\rm Pic}(R)=0$

Then, for all $x\in S^\times$, we have $N(x)=1$ if and only if there exists $y\in S^\times$ such that $x=\dfrac{y}{\sigma(y)}$.

Here, $N(x)=x\sigma(x)\cdots \sigma^{n-1}(x)$, where $n=o(\sigma)$.

**The problem.** For various reasons, I would like a **direct** proof of the previous result **when $R$ is semi-local**.

I tried to adapt the standard proof , known for cyclic field extensions, so the problem boils down to the following question.

**Question.** Assuming that $R$ is a semi-local ring, and given $x\in S^\times$ such that $N(x)=1$, does there exists $z\in S$ such that the quantity $y=z+x\sigma(z)+(x\sigma(x))\sigma^2(z)+\cdots+(x\sigma(x)\cdots\sigma^{n-2}(x))\sigma^{n-1}(z)$ is a unit of $S$ ?

If it makes things simpler, I will be satisfied to get an elementary argument in the following special case: $S=L\otimes_F R$, where $L$ and $F$ are finite fields and $R$ is a finite dimensional commutative $F$-algebra (hence $R$ and $S$ are also finite)

Of course I will be happy with  any other elementary method to get the desired result.

Comment: Wish I knew how this goes more generally. The only kind of Galois rings I have ever worked with were Galois extensions of $\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$ (=the rings of $p$-adic integers of an unramified extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ modulo $p^n$). I would think that in that case claims like these can be resolved by reducing them to the field case (i.e. modulo the unique maximal ideal). Wonder whether something similar works in the semi-local case. It's been a while :-(